# Remove dataframe row containing a specific in a list value from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I a have a dataframe `df`:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   string1 string4 [string7, string10, ...] [string11, string 12] [string15, ...]
1   string2 string5 [string8, ...] [string13, ...] [string16, ...]
2   string3 string6 [string9, ...] [string14, ...] [string17, ...]
```

and a list `to_delete`:

```
to_delete = [string7, string9, string17]
```

I want to delete all row in my dataframe containing a string in `to_delete` but I don't know how to use `.isin` with list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can approach in the following steps:

1. You can use `pd.Series.explode()` on each column/element to expand the list of strings into multiple rows, with each row contains only strings (all lists already got expanded / exploded into rows).
2. Then check the dataframe for strings in the `to_delete` list by using `.isin()`.
3. Group by index level 0 (which contains original row index before explode) to aggregate and summarize the multiple rows matching result back into one row (using `.sum()` under `groupby()`).
4. Then `.sum(axis=1)` to check row-wise any matching string to delete.
5. Check for rows with 0 match (those rows to retain) and form a boolean index of the resulting rows.
6. Finally, use `.loc` to filter the rows without matching to retain.

---

```
df.loc[df.apply(pd.Series.explode).isin(to_delete).groupby(level=0).sum().sum(axis=1).eq(0)]
```

**Result:**

```
         A        B          C           D           E
1  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
```

---

The original dataframe can be built for testing from the following codes:

```
data = {'A': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
 'B': ['string4', 'string5', 'string6'],
 'C': [['string7', 'string10'], ['string8'], ['string9']],
 'D': [['string11', 'string 12'], ['string13'], ['string14']],
 'E': [['string15'], ['string16'], ['string17']]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I see there are already a couple answers but I want to pitch in with mine if that's ok. I think [SeaBean's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67776571/11497988) is correct as well and I like that unlike the [other proposed solutio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775891/11497988)n you do not have to specify which columns have the lists.

I cannot explain my solution as well as SeaBean because it is something I ran across a while ago and I honestly came up with it using trial and error.

```
d = {'A':['string1','string2','string3'],
     'B':['string4','string5','string6'],
     'C':[['string7','string10'],['string8'],['string9']],
     'D':[['string11','string12'],['string13'],['string14']]
     'E':[['string15'],['string16'],['string17']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d);
res = df[~df.stack().explode().isin(to_delete).any(level=0)]
```

I have tried timing them with way more items and it seems my solution is slightly better.

```
d = {'A':['string1','string2','string3']*10000, 'B':['string4','string5','string6']*10000, 'C':[['string7','string10'],['string8'],['string9']]*10000,'D':[['string11','string12'],['string13'],['string14']]*10000,'E':[['string15'],['string16'],['string17']]*10000}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d);

to_delete = ['string7', 'string9', 'string17']


start = time.time()
print(df[~df.stack().explode().isin(to_delete).any(level=0)])
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

start = time.time()
print(df.loc[df.apply(pd.Series.explode).isin(to_delete).groupby(level=0).sum().sum(axis=1).eq(0)])
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Output:

```
             A        B          C           D           E
1      string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
4      string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
7      string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
10     string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
13     string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
...        ...      ...        ...         ...         ...
29986  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29989  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29992  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29995  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29998  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
                                                          
[10000 rows x 5 columns]                                  
0.08804535865783691                                       
             A        B          C           D           E
1      string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
4      string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
7      string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
10     string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
13     string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
...        ...      ...        ...         ...         ...
29986  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29989  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29992  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29995  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
29998  string2  string5  [string8]  [string13]  [string16]
                                                          
[10000 rows x 5 columns]                                  
0.11187744140625
```

Answer (score 0):

The worst solution I can think of is using `apply`:

```
g = lambda x: (set(to_delete) - df[x].apply(set)).str.len()==len(to_delete)

res = df[g('C') & g('D') & g('E')]
```

**df(input):**

```
    A           B           C                       D                       E
0   string1     string4     [string7, string10]     [string11, string12]    [string15]
1   string2     string5     [string8]               [string13]              [string16]
2   string3     string6     [string9]               [string14]              [string17]
```

**res:**

```
    A           B           C            D          E
1   string2     string5     [string8]   [string13]  [string16]
```